# rails, finding a incremental number to use for cache busting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails, I would like to find an incremental number that increases or at least changes with everyone deployment or git commit/push.

I need this for cache busting the CDN.

```
config.action_controller.asset_path = proc { |asset_path|
  "/rel-#{RELEASE_NUMBER}#{asset_path}"
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like?

```
def release_sha
  @release_sha ||= `git log -1 --pretty=format:%h 2>/dev/null`
end
```

You could do one better with this approach and get the SHA for different folders/files.

```
def release_sha(path=nil)
  @release_sha ||= {}
  @release_sha[path] ||= `git log -1 --pretty=format:%h #{path} 2>/dev/null`
end
```

Then call it like `release_sha('/public/images')` for the latest SHA for that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the current timestamp (epoch)..

```
Time.now.usec
```

You can write this value to a constant and put it in config/initlaizers/cache_buster.rb for example with a script (or write your own rake task)..

Comment: can't do that because it would change every request. I need it static per deployment so the CDN doesn't keep refreshing the content.

Comment: I realized that after I typed my inital response, I added the suggestion of writing that value to a file in initializers that sets a constant.. I actually do exactly this in my php app and use it to create a directory in a CDN